# How to connect to internal server via WWW

Tags: intranet

Was wondering if its possible to connect to an internal server on the domain via WWW?

Lets say the internal machine i want is at 192.168.10.200.

Its running IIS / Sharepoint or whatever, something that a webbrowser understands.

The external user has, lets say, 81.200.72.122 and this goes to the SBS server. When you get there it has several choices like outlook, a list of computers to connect to and finally an internal website. This internal website link should go not to the default but to the machine at 192.168.10.200. Surely this cant be done?

Comment: Huh? You really need to reword the question into something meaningful.

Comment: totally! sorry rushed ...

Comment: Im thinking at the moment perhaps something to do with proxy server or dns settings?

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do this after all. just set port forwarding to any of the attached ip's in the router.